# Gulp вылетает и зависает

Tags: html, css, gulp, scss

[image: Раздел сеть в консоли разработчика Google Chrome]Не так давно я начал обнаруживать что моя сборка постоянно вылетает или зависает. Каждый раз её нужно перезагружать через cmd. Это очень сильно напрягает. При зависании все стили scss и html-теги которые добавил не загружаются на страницу. В терминале при сохранении html и scss обновление происходит нормально (никаких ошибок нет).

```js
const { src, dest, watch, parallel, series }  = require('gulp');

const scss          = require('gulp-sass');
const concat        = require('gulp-concat');
const browserSync   = require('browser-sync').create();
const uglify        = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
const autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const imagemin      = require('gulp-imagemin');
const del           = require('del');

function browsersync() {
  browserSync.init({
    server : {
      baseDir: 'app/'
    }
  });
}

function cleanDist() {
  return del('dist')
}

function images() {
  return src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe(imagemin(
      [
        imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: true }),
        imagemin.mozjpeg({ quality: 75, progressive: true }),
        imagemin.optipng({ optimizationLevel: 5 }),
        imagemin.svgo({
          plugins: [
            { removeViewBox: true },
            { cleanupIDs: false }
          ]
        })
      ]
    ))
    .pipe(dest('dist/images'))
}

function scripts() {
  return src([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'app/js/main.js'
  ])
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(dest('app/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}


function styles() {
  return src('app/scss/style.scss')
      .pipe(scss({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
      .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
      .pipe(autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['last 10 version'],
        grid: true
      }))
      .pipe(dest('app/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}

function build() {
  return src([
    'app/css/style.min.css',
    'app/fonts/**/*',
    'app/js/main.min.js',
    'app/*.html'
  ], {base: 'app'})
    .pipe(dest('dist'))
}

function watching() {
  watch(['app/scss/**/*.scss'], styles);
  watch(['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/js/main.min.js'], scripts);
  watch(['app/*.html']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.styles = styles;
exports.watching = watching;
exports.browsersync = browsersync;
exports.scripts = scripts;
exports.images = images;
exports.cleanDist = cleanDist;


exports.build = series(cleanDist, images, build);
exports.default = parallel(styles ,scripts ,browsersync, watching);
```

Comment: В последних версиях `sass` же по другому подключается `require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'))`. В терминале у вас никаких ошибок нет?

Comment: нет, в терминале ошибок нет. Все корректно отображается в браузере, за исключением того что периодически gulp не компилирует scss в css, а так же выходит сообщение о том, что интернет подключение разорвано.

Comment: Ну так вы сообщения об ошибках не выводите `src.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сам решил этот вопрос. Оказывается в браузере, (я работаю в Google Chrome) в консоли разработчика был включен ограничитель трафика.